# ListView Movement Problem

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-mobile, winapi

I am using Listview,the View selected is largeicon mode. The problem i am facing is selection.using the arrow-keys i am able to navigate only in the first row(suppose i have 3 images in a row,if i press right arrow key,it will move till the end of row and again it will comeback to the first image of the same row)But the expected behavior is it should go to the next row first icon..as a remedy i have handled the key down event still.. if i do focus next item manually it is not taking the focused item,instead it will go next of it..i mean 2 item jump taking place.i am not getting no how to avoid this,i think we need to set some style? or the feature of list view only like this? i don't no.. please help me how to make this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only handling keydown then it may be that the current keypress is still being processed (e.g. the move right), but you have already moved the focus to the item on the next row, and so when the key up happens it moves the focus on to the 2nd item.

Try setting the Handled property to true of the KeyEventArgs object that is passed to your keydown method, as well as moving the focus.

Comment: you rock.. it worked for me.. i set "e.Handled = true" Thats trick
Thanks Lot